# Automatically replace outlying values with missing values

Tags: sas

Suppose the data set `have` contains various outliers which have been identified in an `outliers` data set.  These outliers need to be replaced with missing values, as demonstrated below.

**Have**

```
   Obs    group    replicate     height     weight         bp    cholesterol

     1      1          A          0.406      0.887      0.262        0.683
     2      1          B          0.656      0.700      0.083        0.836
     3      1          C          0.645      0.711      0.349        0.383
     4      1          D          0.115      0.266    666.000        0.015
     5      2          A          0.607      0.247      0.644        0.915
     6      2          B          0.172    333.000    555.000        0.924
     7      2          C          0.680      0.417      0.269        0.499
     8      2          D          0.787      0.260      0.610        0.142
     9      3          A          0.406      0.099      0.263      111.000
    10      3          B          0.981    444.000      0.971        0.894
    11      3          C          0.436      0.502      0.563        0.580
    12      3          D          0.814      0.959      0.829        0.245
    13      4          A          0.488      0.273      0.463        0.784
    14      4          B          0.141      0.117      0.674        0.103
    15      4          C          0.152      0.935      0.250        0.800
    16      4          D        222.000      0.247      0.778        0.941
```

**Want**

```
     Obs    group    replicate    height    weight      bp      cholesterol

       1      1          A        0.4056    0.8870    0.2615       0.6827
       2      1          B        0.6556    0.6995    0.0829       0.8356
       3      1          C        0.6445    0.7110    0.3492       0.3826
       4      1          D        0.1146    0.2655     .           0.0152
       5      2          A        0.6072    0.2474    0.6444       0.9154
       6      2          B        0.1720     .         .           0.9241
       7      2          C        0.6800    0.4166    0.2686       0.4992
       8      2          D        0.7874    0.2595    0.6099       0.1418
       9      3          A        0.4057    0.0988    0.2632        .
      10      3          B        0.9805     .        0.9712       0.8937
      11      3          C        0.4358    0.5023    0.5626       0.5799
      12      3          D        0.8138    0.9588    0.8293       0.2448
      13      4          A        0.4881    0.2731    0.4633       0.7839
      14      4          B        0.1413    0.1166    0.6743       0.1032
      15      4          C        0.1522    0.9351    0.2504       0.8003
      16      4          D         .        0.2465    0.7782       0.9412
```

The "get it done" approach is to manually enter each variable/value combination in a conditional which replaces with missing when true.

```
data have;
  input group replicate $ height weight bp cholesterol;
  datalines;
1 A 0.4056 0.8870 0.2615 0.6827
1 B 0.6556 0.6995 0.0829 0.8356
1 C 0.6445 0.7110 0.3492 0.3826
1 D 0.1146 0.2655 666    0.0152
2 A 0.6072 0.2474 0.6444 0.9154
2 B 0.1720 333    555    0.9241
2 C 0.6800 0.4166 0.2686 0.4992
2 D 0.7874 0.2595 0.6099 0.1418
3 A 0.4057 0.0988 0.2632 111   
3 B 0.9805 444    0.9712 0.8937
3 C 0.4358 0.5023 0.5626 0.5799
3 D 0.8138 0.9588 0.8293 0.2448
4 A 0.4881 0.2731 0.4633 0.7839
4 B 0.1413 0.1166 0.6743 0.1032
4 C 0.1522 0.9351 0.2504 0.8003
4 D 222    0.2465 0.7782 0.9412
;
run;

data outliers;
  input parameter $ 11. group replicate $ measurement;
  datalines;
cholesterol 3  A  111
height      4  D  222
weight      2  B  333
weight      3  B  444
bp          2  B  555
bp          1  D  666
  ;
run;
```

EDIT: Updated `outliers` so that `parameter` avoids truncation and changed `measurement` to be numeric type so as to match the corresponding `height`, `weight`, `bp`, `cholesterol`.  This shouldn't change the responses.

```
data want;
  set have;

  if group = 3 and replicate = 'A' and cholesterol  = 111 then cholesterol = .;
  if group = 4 and replicate = 'D' and height       = 222 then height      = .;
  if group = 2 and replicate = 'B' and weight       = 333 then weight      = .;
  if group = 3 and replicate = 'B' and weight       = 444 then weight      = .;
  if group = 2 and replicate = 'B' and bp           = 555 then bp          = .;
  if group = 1 and replicate = 'D' and bp           = 666 then bp          = .;
run;
```

This, however, doesn't utilize the `outliers` data set.  How can the replacement process be made automatic?

---

I immediately think of the `IN=` operator, but that won't work.  It's not the entire row which needs to be matched.  Perhaps an SQL key matching approach would work? But to match the key, don't I need to use a `where` statement?  I'd then effectively be writing everything out manually again.  I could probably create macro variables which contain the various `if` or `where` statements, but that seems excessive.

Comment: check out the sas update statement

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier for each row?

Comment: In your example, anything over 100 would be an outlier. Is that your rule in general? It may be easier to load the levels into a temporary array and then use an array to loop and assign it to missing.

Comment: The group/replicate can be considered a unique identifier. And, no, the outliers could be any value. I had used those dummy values for myself to facilitate creating fake data and then later realized that it introduced a pattern.  However, I decided to leave them in as the technique used in a patterned case could be different from the general case, yet still be informative.  If this goes against SO protocol, I'll gladly update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think generating statements is excessive in this case. The complexity arises here because your outlier dataset cannot be merged easily since the `parameter` values represent variable names in the `have` dataset. If it is possible to reorient the outliers dataset so you have a 1 to 1 merge, this logic would be simpler.

Let's assume you cannot. There are a few ways to use a variable in a dataset that corresponds to a variable in another.

- You could use an array like `array params{*} height -- cholesterol;` and then use the `vname` function as you loop through the array to compare to the value in the `parameter` variable, but this gets complicated in your case because you have a one to many merge, so you would have to retain the replacements and only output the last record for each by group... so it gets complicated.
- You could transpose the outliers data using `proc transpose`, but that will get lengthy because you will need a transpose for each `parameter`, and then you'd need to merge all the transposed datasets back to the `have` dataset. My main issue with this method is that code with a bunch of transposes like that gets unwieldy.
- You create the macro variable logic you are thinking might be excessive. But compared to the other ways of getting the values of the `parameter` variable to match up with the variable names in the `have` dataset, I don't think something like this is excessive:

  ```
  data _null_;
      set outliers;
      call symput("outlierstatement"||_n_,"if group = "||group||" and replicate = '"||replicate||"' and "||parameter||" = "||measurement||" then "|| parameter ||" = .;");
      call symput("outliercount",_n_);
  run;

  %macro makewant();
      data want;
          set have;
          %do i = 1 %to &outliercount;
              &&outlierstatement&i;
          %end;
      run;
  %mend;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Lorem:

Transposition is the key to a fully automatic programmatic approach.  The transposition that will occur is of the filter data, not the original data.  The transposed filter data will have fewer rows than the original.  As John indicated, transposition of the want data can create a very tall table and has to be transposed back after applying the filters.

As to the the filter data, the presence of a filter row for a specific group, replicate and parameter should be enough to mark a cell for filtering.  This is on the presumption that you have a system for automatic outlier detection and the filter values will always be in concordance with the original values.

So, what has to be done to automate the filter application process without code generating a wall of test and assign statements ?

1. Transpose filter data into same form as want data, call it Filter^
2. Merge Want and Filter^ by record key (which is the by group of Group and Replicate)
3. Array process the data elements, looking for filtering conditions.

For your consideration, try the following SAS code.  There is an erroneous filter record added to the mix.

```
data have;
  input group replicate $ height weight bp cholesterol;
  datalines;
1 A 0.4056 0.8870 0.2615 0.6827
1 B 0.6556 0.6995 0.0829 0.8356
1 C 0.6445 0.7110 0.3492 0.3826
1 D 0.1146 0.2655 666    0.0152
2 A 0.6072 0.2474 0.6444 0.9154
2 B 0.1720 333    555    0.9241
2 C 0.6800 0.4166 0.2686 0.4992
2 D 0.7874 0.2595 0.6099 0.1418
3 A 0.4057 0.0988 0.2632 111   
3 B 0.9805 444    0.9712 0.8937
3 C 0.4358 0.5023 0.5626 0.5799
3 D 0.8138 0.9588 0.8293 0.2448
4 A 0.4881 0.2731 0.4633 0.7839
4 B 0.1413 0.1166 0.6743 0.1032
4 C 0.1522 0.9351 0.2504 0.8003
4 D 222    0.2465 0.7782 0.9412
5 E 222    0.2465 0.7782 0.9412  /* test record for filter value misalignment test */
;
run;

data outliers;
  length parameter $32;  %* <--- widened parameter so it can transposed into column via id;
  input parameter $ group replicate $ measurement ; %* <--- changed measurement to numeric variable;
  datalines;
cholesterol 3  A  111
height      4  D  222
height      5  E  223  /* test record for filter value misalignment test */
weight      2  B  333
weight      3  B  444
bp          2  B  555
bp          1  D  666
  ;
run;

data want;
  set have;

  if group = 3 and replicate = 'A' and cholesterol  = 111 then cholesterol = .;
  if group = 4 and replicate = 'D' and height       = 222 then height      = .;
  if group = 2 and replicate = 'B' and weight       = 333 then weight      = .;
  if group = 3 and replicate = 'B' and weight       = 444 then weight      = .;
  if group = 2 and replicate = 'B' and bp           = 555 then bp          = .;
  if group = 1 and replicate = 'D' and bp           = 666 then bp          = .;
run;

/* Create a view with 1st row having all the filtered parameters
 * This is necessary so that the first transposed filter row 
 * will have the parameters as columns in alphabetic order;
 */

proc sql noprint;
  create view outliers_transpose_ready as
  select distinct parameter from outliers
  union
  select * from outliers
  order by group, replicate, parameter
;

  /* Generate a alphabetic ordered list of parameters for use 
   * as a variable (aka column) list in the filter application step */
  select distinct parameter 
  into :parameters separated by ' '
  from outliers
  order by parameter
;
quit;

%put NOTE: &=parameters;

/* tranpose the filter data
 * The ID statement pivots row data into column names.
 * The prefix=_filter_ ensure the new column names
 * will not collide with the original data, and can be
 * the shortcut listed with _filter_: in an array statement.
 */

proc transpose data=outliers_transpose_ready out=outliers_apply_ready prefix=_filter_;
  by group replicate notsorted;
  id parameter;
  var measurement;
run;

/* Robust production code should contain a bin for
 * data that does not conform to the filter application conditions
 */

data 
  want2(label="Outlier filtering applied" drop=_i_ _filter_:)
  want2_warnings(label="Outlier filtering: misaligned values")
;
  merge have outliers_apply_ready(keep=group replicate _filter_:);
  by group replicate;

  /* The arrays are for like named columns 
   * due to the alphabetic ordering enforced in data and codegen preparation
   */
  array value_filter_check _filter_:;
  array value &parameters;

  if group ne .;

  do _i_ = 1 to dim(value);

    if value(_i_) EQ value_filter_check(_i_) then
      value(_i_) = .;
    else
    if not missing(value_filter_check(_i_)) AND
       value(_i_) NE value_filter_check(_i_)
    then do;
      put 'WARNING: Filtering expected but values do not match. ' group= replicate= value(_i_)=  value_filter_check(_i_)=;
      output want2_warnings;
    end;
  end;

  output want2;
run;
```

Confirm your want and automated want2 agree.

```
proc compare noprint data=want compare=want2 outnoequal out=diffs;
  by group replicate;
run;
```

Enjoy your SAS

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table.  Load a hash table with the outlier dataset, with parameter-group-replicate defined as the key.  Then read in the data, and as you read each record, check each of the variables to see if that combination of parameter-group-replicate can be found in the hash table.  I think below works (I'm no hash expert):

```
data want;
  if 0 then set outliers (keep=parameter group replicate);
  if _N_ = 1 then
    do;   
      declare hash h(dataset:'outliers') ; 
      h.defineKey('parameter', 'group', 'replicate') ;
      h.defineDone() ;
    end;
  set have ;

  array vars {*} height weight bp cholesterol ;

  do i=1 to dim(vars);
    parameter=vname(vars{i});
    if h.check()=0 then call missing(vars{i});
  end;

  drop i parameter;
run;
```

Comment: I don't think the `if 0 then` statement is necessary since you reference `dataset: outliers` in the hash declaration statement, but I may be mistaken.  It's difficult to be sure with hash because the documentation itself contains errors.

Comment: Before the defineDone() executes, the variables in the hash table need to be in the PDV.  If you comment out the `if 0 then` it will error.  The DECLARE statement can't add variables the PDV, even when you specify a dataset.  Most of the SAS docs use a length statement to add variables to the PDV, but I think `if 0 then` is easier.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error you speak of.  The behavior I observe is identical with or without the `if 0 then`.  My understanding is that  `declare hash` uses the `dataset:` argument to instantiate.  That is, the data set provided in the `dataset:` argument is used to define the keys listed in the `defineKey` statement. https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lecompobjref/69740/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p00ilfw5pzcjvtn1nfya9863fozd.htm#p04u7k0pr34yxjn13idjdtdpp8o4

Comment: In this case, you are right there is no error without `if 0 then set` because `group` and `replicate` are added to the PDV by `set have ;` and `parameter` is added to the PDV by the assignment statement at the end.  Using the `if 0 then set` does have the benefit of making parameter be the same length as the source data, rather than $200.   This example will error because name is NOT in the  PDV: `data want; *if 0 then set sashelp.class (keep=name); declare hash h(dataset:'sashelp.class') ; h.defineKey('name') ;  h.defineDone() ;  stop;run;`

Answer (score 1):

I like @John's suggestion:

> You could use an array like array params{*} height -- cholesterol; and
>   then use the vname function as you loop through the array to compare
>   to the value in the parameter variable, but this gets complicated in
>   your case because you have a one to many merge, so you would have to
>   retain the replacements and only output the last record for each by
>   group... so it gets complicated.

Generally in a one to many merge I would avoid recoding variables from the dataset that is unique, because variables are retained within BY groups.  But in this case, it works out well.

```
proc sort data=outliers;
  by group replicate;
run;

data want (keep=group replicate height weight bp cholesterol);
  merge have (in=a)
        outliers (keep=group replicate parameter in=b)
  ;
  by group replicate;

  array vars {*} height weight bp cholesterol ;

  do i=1 to dim(vars);
    if vname(vars{i})=parameter then call missing(vars{i});
  end;

  if last.replicate;
run;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you decided to use `in=`?  Are you able to clarify?

Comment: Probaby just habit.  I would often add something like `if a=0 then put "ERROR: " (group replicate)(=);` just to protect against any surprises in the outliers dataset.

Comment: Good call.  In my case, the `outliers` data set is coming from a colleague.  I hadn't considered the situation where the outlier creation was automated and could return a blank data set.

Comment: Was thinking more about defending against the outlier dataset having a typo or similar such that it had a value for group or replicate which never matched to the HAVE dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @John for providing a proof of concept.  My implementation is a little different and I think worth making a separate entry for posterity.  I went with a macro variable approach because I feel it is the most intuitive, being a simple text replacement.  However, since a macro variable can contain only 65534 characters, it is conceivable that there could be sufficient outliers to exceed this limit.  In such a case, any of the other solutions would make fine alternatives.  Note that it is important that the `put` statement use something like `best32.`  Too short a width will truncate the value.

If you desire to have a dataset containing the `if` statements (perhaps for verification), simply remove the `into :` statement and place a `create table statements as` line at the beginning of the `PROC SQL` step.

```
data have;
  input group replicate $ height weight bp cholesterol;
  datalines;
1 A 0.4056 0.8870 0.2615 0.6827
1 B 0.6556 0.6995 0.0829 0.8356
1 C 0.6445 0.7110 0.3492 0.3826
1 D 0.1146 0.2655 666    0.0152
2 A 0.6072 0.2474 0.6444 0.9154
2 B 0.1720 333    555    0.9241
2 C 0.6800 0.4166 0.2686 0.4992
2 D 0.7874 0.2595 0.6099 0.1418
3 A 0.4057 0.0988 0.2632 111   
3 B 0.9805 444    0.9712 0.8937
3 C 0.4358 0.5023 0.5626 0.5799
3 D 0.8138 0.9588 0.8293 0.2448
4 A 0.4881 0.2731 0.4633 0.7839
4 B 0.1413 0.1166 0.6743 0.1032
4 C 0.1522 0.9351 0.2504 0.8003
4 D 222    0.2465 0.7782 0.9412
;
run;

data outliers;
  input parameter $ 11. group replicate $ measurement;
  datalines;
cholesterol 3  A  111
height      4  D  222
weight      2  B  333
weight      3  B  444
bp          2  B  555
bp          1  D  666
  ;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select 
    cat('if group = '
      , strip(put(group, best32.))
      , " and replicate = '"
      , strip(replicate)
      , "' and "
      , strip(parameter)
      , ' = '
      , strip(put(measurement, best32.))
      , ' then '
      , strip(parameter)
      , ' = . ;')
  into : listIfs separated by ' '
  from outliers
  ;
quit;

%put %quote(&listIfs);

data want;
  set have;
  &listIfs;
run;
```